# Comparaison of L value in GrayScale image with Y value in YUV image

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

In some comments on previous questions, people told me that `Y` value of a `YUV` image converted using:

```
image_in_yuv=cv2.cvtColor(image_in_bgr,cv2.COLOR_BGR2YUV)
```

is the same as the `L` value of the same image in its grayscale color space converted using

```
image_in_grayscale=cv2.imred('image.png',cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
```

I wonder how is this true ? because on my side when I run for example:

```
print image_in_yuv[200,200,0] # Y will be printed
print image_in_grayscale[200,200] # L will be printed
```

I get **different** values of `Y` and `L` for the pixel (200,200)

So did I misunderstand something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conversion of an RGB image into grayscale and YUV uses different numerical values. The `Y` channel *is* the "grayscale component" in the image, only in the sense that it denotes brightness. In fact, if I recall correct, the range of `Y` is 16-235.

Check  out [colour conversion](http://www.equasys.de/colorconversion.html) and 
[grayscale](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2009/08/24/algorithms-convert-color-grayscale/).